# Count from two tables and sort it out by the number of exist SQL

Tags: mysql, count, sql-order-by, mysql-workbench, join

I’ve trying to list out a table with numbers that exist more than three time. As you can see, I am new to SQL. I am a bit unsure about the syntaxes and possibilities with SQL.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT tabel1.nr, count(tabel2.opp)
FROM tabel1
JOIN tabel2 on tabel2.opp = tabel1.opp
WHERE tabel2.opp > 3
ORDER BY tabel2.opp
```

This is the idea I’ve trying to figure out:

```
SELECT COUNT(tabel1.key = tabel2.key) as numbers
FROM table1
ORDER BY numbers > 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT tabel1.nr, count(tabel2.opp)
FROM tabel1
JOIN tabel2 on tabel2.opp = tabel1.opp
GROUP BY tabel1.nr
HAVING count(tabel2.opp) > 3
ORDER BY tabel2.opp
```